# Django static files relative references Amazon S3

Tags: python, css, django, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a background image to show hosting the static files on Amazon S3. The following code in my base.html works perfectly well and finds the CSS file located in my S3 bucket:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
```

My question is, within my CSS file, the following line doesn't seem to find the image:

```
    background-image: url("{{ STATIC_URL }}img/GreenBackground.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

My Amazon bucket looks like

```
/newdjangoapp
--/admin
--/css
----/stylesheet.css
--/img
----/GreenBackground.jpg
```

I have tried adding an additional 'static' directory around the img and css directories and updating this in the filepaths, I have tried the following code:

```
    background-image: url("{{ STATIC_URL }}../img/GreenBackground.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

and even

```
    background-image: url("../img/GreenBackground.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

My static URL setup is as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME +'/'
```

and static directories...

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

Any help on getting this fixed would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be using relative paths in your CSS file like your last example: `background-image: url("../img/GreenBackground.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;`. What does the link say when you View Source of the page with your image specified relatively?

Comment: I think you don't have to use {{STATIC_URL}} in your CSS file just dot(s) only to find the exact location of the image

Comment: @DanHoerst When I view the source it shows me the link to the CSS file which in turn shows me the following line (in reference to the image):

`background-image: url("../img/GreenBackground.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;`

Should it be showing a full link to the image in the CSS? Because, with the above file structure I should be navigating out of the CSS subdirectory, into the img subdirectory and finding the image which just isn't happening.

Comment: No it still will not show the full link in the CSS file. Clicking the relative link will bring you to the full link. Where does it bring you?

Comment: @DanHoerst Clicking on the relative link doesn't seem to do anything unless I'm much mistaken - clicking on the CSS link from the view source part of the homepage (http://afternoon-beach-5071.herokuapp.com/) takes me to the CSS file but there's no clickable link in the CSS file to go to the image.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should reference it differently since your css does not know {{ STATIC_URL }}.  See how you defined static in your django settings.py file ( in my case I have it "/static/ ) and then reference it like that in the css file. Instead of {{STATIC_URL}}, make your reference the same as you made in your settings.py file (in my case that would be "/static/css...")

Comment: @JeffBauer So in my case (just using the project directory as the static root and the Amazon bucket as my static URL) do I have to navigate all the way from the project root to the image file? i.e. appname/static/img/GreenBackground.img or can I not take advantage of the fact that my CSS file is in the same subdirectory as my image?